# Iterate over columns of Pandas dataframe and create new variables

Tags: python, pandas, nested-for-loop

I am having trouble figuring out how to iterate over variables in a pandas dataframe and perform same arithmetic function on each.

I have a dataframe `df` that contain three numeric variables `x1`, `x2` and `x3`. I want to create three new variables by multiplying each by 2. Here’s what I am doing:

```
existing = ['x1','x2','x3']
new = ['y1','y2','y3']

for i in existing:
    for j in new:
        df[j] = df[i]*2
```

Above code is in fact creating three new variables `y1`, `y2` and `y3` in the dataframe. But the values of `y1` and `y2` are being overridden by the values of `y3` and all three variables have same values, corresponding to that of `y3`. I am not sure what I am missing.

Really appreciate any guidance/ suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping something like 9 times here - 3 times for each column, with each iteration overwriting the previous.

You may want something like

```
for e, n in zip(existing,new):
    df[n] = df[e]*2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more generic

```
#existing = ['x1','x2','x3']
exisiting = df.columns
new = existing.replace('x','y') 
#maybe you need map+lambda/for for each existing string

for (ind_existing, ind_new) in zip(existing,new):
    df[new[ind_new]] = df[existing[ind_existing]]*2 
#maybe there is more elegant way by using pandas assign function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenante the original DataFrame with the columns with doubled values:

```py
cols_to_double = ['x0', 'x1', 'x2']
new_cols = list(df.columns) + [c.replace('x', 'y') for c in cols_to_double]

df = pd.concat([df, 2 * df[cols_to_double]], axis=1, copy=True)
df.columns = new_cols
```

So, if your input `df` Dataframe is:

```sh
   x0  x1  x2  other0  other1
0   0   1   2       3       4
1   0   1   2       3       4
2   0   1   2       3       4
3   0   1   2       3       4
4   0   1   2       3       4
```

after executing the previous lines, you get:

```sh
   x0  x1  x2  other0  other1  y0  y1  y2
0   0   1   2       3       4   0   2   4
1   0   1   2       3       4   0   2   4
2   0   1   2       3       4   0   2   4
3   0   1   2       3       4   0   2   4
4   0   1   2       3       4   0   2   4
```

Here the code to create `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=np.column_stack([np.full((5,), i) for i in range(5)]),
    columns=[f'x{i}' for i in range(3)] + [f'other{i}' for i in range(2)]
)
```